# How can i capture result of requests.POST in Python?

Tags: python, api, postman

I am quite new to Python and was trying to simulate the result captured when testing API POST requests in Postman. I am basically trying to capture the token generated using the Post method.

I have the following details in Postman which gives me the token details.

**Authorization Tab:**  ***Type:*** Basic Auth, ***Username***, ***Password***

**Headers Tab:**  **Content-Type**: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, ***Authorization:*** #This is Auto-Filled

**Body Tab**: ***raw:*** grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read_snfa_unifiedgateway

Now when i run with above details in Postman, it gives me access token in the result but when i use the same details using the following Python Code, i get only `<Response [200]>` as result for **response** variable.

```
import requests
url = 'https://appurl.com/oauth/ls/connect/token'
body = 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read_snfa_unifiedgateway'
response = requests.post(
        url,
        body, 
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth('my_username', 'my_password'), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        )
```

How can i change the above Python code in such a way that i could get the result in the format i get in Postman as following and then i could use the access_token value in next operation for another POST Method?

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbsdfsdfsdfsdfcsdcsdvarglkwelkrmgmasdmnfjtugnasmdfisdfmmmmpeirhg_-e60s72zgV8Gn2hUiWwlelNQhJongUW6fxwD42c1N5u4R2JJdrj5V_bIwnvY_C_l5wHlIFSQRE1E-5KzP7WG9XjmV9oXRXXGjNhwRqEocGdiEMjcibyiYQNZmG2h-GbsTKvCc21hRNhyRF_y4mdwVUytAXT68TuwZxsTbjUzEvPdwd2JZaFnD9Elo7akSk2ROnRMxN70fsoLzEK71kbzoYkti1jX_V8i_s6K0wmLma-x4nc2kW5mpFM0R9NPqH-kGf-4ZUKim03frifpsGl6Nqo-eN5oZ-b6YgK56mSjxpxQ",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `response.json()` to get result in dict format. You can use

`access_token = response.json()['access_token']`

Comment: Great. Is there any way i could encrypt those credentials as well? I believe these will be currently readable both in script and during request which is sent to the appAPI.